# Expression française équivalente à 藁にもすがる思い « je me saisirais même de bottes de paille » ?

Tags: expressions, japonais

Je m'interroge sur une expression courante française équivalente à 藁にもすがる思い (wara ni mo sugaru omoi). Par exemple, je dirais :

> On a déjà tout essayé pour résoudre ce problème, mais à chaque fois, on se heurte à un échec cuisant. **On se saisirait désormais de n’importe quoi, même de bottes de paille !**

Cette expression s'emploie pour décrire :

Dans une situation désespérée dont on ne voit pas d’issue, on s'accroche à la moindre lueur d'espoir. C’est tout comme on se raccrocherait même à des bottes de paille si on était sur le point de se noyer, tout en sachant que l'on ne peut décemment pas compter sur une chose aussi extrêmement légère pour nous en tirer.

Comment: c'est amusant, apparement il y a exactement la même expression en russe: http://www.russievirtuelle.com/locutions/19/568.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On a déjà tout essayé pour résoudre ce problème, mais à chaque fois, on se heurte à un échec cuisant. **On en est réduit à faire feu de tout bois.**

Mais «faire feu de tout bois» me semble moins désespéré que «saisir une botte de paille».

*Edit to add:* Dans un autre registre (desespéré, moins offensif), assez proche de l’expression japonaise, si on remplace la noyade par la chute d‘un arbre, il y a aussi «se raccrocher aux branches».

Comment: Hi. I believe your two suggestions hit the nail, capturing the idea of "leaving no stone unturned". Merci.

Answer (score 5):

On ne sait plus à quel saint se vouer.

Answer (score 4):

Le proverbe le plus proche me semble être:

> A situation désespérée, solution désespérée.

Answer (score 2):

Devant une situation où l'on a tout tenté, on pourrait dire :

> Jouer son va-tout

Answer (score 1):

Voici quelques propositions qui me semblent convenir :

> On a déjà tout essayé pour résoudre ce problème, mais à chaque fois, on se heurte à un échec cuisant.
>
> - On va attaquer sur tous les fronts.
> - On va employer tous les moyens.
> - On va tirer tous azimuts.

Answer (score 0):

Dans notre civilisation judéo-chrétienne, on se dit "qu'il faudrait un miracle".

Comment: Hi. Mais quelqu'un qui se noie ne dirait pas « il me faudrait un miracle pour en réchapper... » sur un ton défaitiste... L’idée, c’est plutôt que je ne baisse jamais les bras, loin s'en faut ; je suis prêt à tout pour m’en sortir, survivre.